# RadEditor ExportToDocx Changing Font Size

Tags: c#, telerik, docx, radeditor

I'm using the Telerik RadEditor to do a docx export of the contents, but the DefaultFontSizeInPoints does not appear to be overriding the size of the font on export like I would expect based on their documentation. Regardless of what I use as a value, it always comes out the same size.

```
<telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="txtLogText" Width="100%" Height="100%" ContentAreaMode="iFrame" Enabled="true" 
ExternalDialogsPath="~/UserControls/" StripFormattingOptions="NoneSupressCleanMessage" 
ContentFilters="DefaultFilters, PdfExportFilter" EditModes="Design" OnClientLoad="OnClientLoad" Skin="Default">
<CssFiles>
    <telerik:EditorCssFile Value="" />
</CssFiles>
<ExportSettings>
    <Docx DefaultFontName="Arial" DefaultFontSizeInPoints="8" HeaderFontSizeInPoints="8" PageHeader="System Log, Confidential" />
</ExportSettings>
<Tools>
    <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Copy" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name="SelectAll" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name="FindAndReplace" />
        <telerik:EditorSeparator />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Print" />
        </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
</Tools>
```

Thank you for any help or suggestions on correcting this problem.

Comment: Does your content have explicit font size set in the HTML?

Comment: Yes. But it's not coming out at that font size or type either.

Comment: If you have your own font defined, you should not expect a default setting to take effect, what you have in the markup is a fallback value in case you have no font settings in the HTML.So, I would expect to see the font setting from the HTML in  Word, not the DefaultFont* from the markup. Or are you getting something entirely different? Clarifiy your problem, post some example input and output.